# Relating $N(α)$ to $|α|$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

Consider $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$. What would be an equation relating $N(α)$ to $|α|$ which is the natural absolute value defined for complex numbers? For which $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ is this formula correct?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem - if so, what did you try and what definitions do you know?

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's not homework to me, because it isn't assigned to me. I am self learning this and came across this quesrtion in lecture notes.

Comment: I would suggest checking out this [quadratic integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer#Norm_and_conjugation) to see if it answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equation considering $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220415/equation-considering-mathbb-q-sqrt-1-and-mathbb-q-sqrtd)