# Equation considering $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So first consider $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$. Now, can someone explain to me and show me an equation relating $N(α)$ to $|α|$. For info, $|α|$ is the natural absolute value defined for complex numbers. Also, for which $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ would the formula be correct as wel?

Comment: what book are you reading????

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of your [prior question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219335/242) 22 hours ago?

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes it is. I didn't get a clear answer.

Comment: @WillJagy I am using intro to number theory by stark

Comment: @WillJagy Can you help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbf Q(\sqrt d)$ ($d$ square-free integer), and $\alpha=a+\sqrt d\, b$, $N(\alpha)=a^2-db^2$. Thus $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-1})$ is the only case relating $N(\alpha)$ to $\lvert \alpha\rvert$: $\,N(\alpha)=\lvert \alpha\rvert^2$.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you answered the second question.

Comment: Well, what do you want $a^2-db^2$ have to see *for all $a,b$* with $a^2+b^2$?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still dont understand

Comment: You asked if for other value(s) of $d$, $N(\alpha)$ was in some way related to $\,\lvert\alpha\rvert$, and I tried to make feel it's impossible for *all* values of $a,b$ that $\,N(\alpha)$ and $\,\lvert\alpha\rvert$ or $\,\lvert\alpha\rvert^2$ be related. My answer can only be vague, as the question was vague.

Comment: Oh. I see. So that's it. That's the answer, correct?

Comment: Yes, but I'm aware it's not (it can't be) a precise answer.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @dana Presumably he means that it is difficult to be more precise because the question is not precise about what is meant by "related".

Comment: Just that if you ask if a given relation exist, I'll (hopefully) be able to answer precisely.

Comment: If I said that the relation does exist, how would the answer change (become more precise)?

Comment: If you give the relation, I can examine it and maybe have good arguments to say it's true or it's false…